# Write cmd console if program exists or not exists along with failure / success in bacth file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

How to write to command prompt if the program is Installed or not installed using .bat file  ?

Please help to correct the code to add the below :

1. execution is failure / success
2. Write the output response to cmd console .

For example , if program exists , it should write command prompt host like below :

... PROGRAM IS ALREADY INSTALLED

or

... PROGRAM IS NOT INSTALLED

**Code :**

```
    @ECHO off

    TITLE Check and Install MS Visual C++ Redistributable 2015

    SET LOGPATH=D:\Tool\InstallC++Log
    IF NOT EXIST %LOGPATH% MD %LOGPATH%

    SET PowerShellScriptPath=C:\temp\Check_Prog.ps1
    PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%PowerShellScriptPath%" >> %LOGPATH%\Redist.log

echo PROGRAM IS ALREADY INSTALLED

If exists MS Visual C++ Redistributable 2015(

echo PROGRAM IS NOT INSTALLED )

    PAUSE
```

**PowerShell code (C:\temp\Check_Prog.ps1
) :**

```
$TargetApp = 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x86)'

$RegPath = @('HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*')
If ([Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem)
{
    $RegPath += 'HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
}

$Result = Get-ItemProperty -Path $RegPath |
  Where-Object { $PSItem.DisplayName -eq $TargetApp -and
                 $PSItem.UninstallString } |
  Select-Object -Property @('DisplayName','Publisher','InstallDate','DisplayVersion','UninstallString')

If ($Null -eq $Result)
{
    Write-Output "Could not find '$TargetApp'. "

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
If exists MS Visual C++ Redistributable 2015(
```

should be:

```
If exist "MS Visual C++ Redistributable 2015" (
```

(note the space before the `(` and the qoutes around the name)

But how about:

```
wmic product where caption="Java Auto Updater" get name /value 2>nul |find "=" >nul && echo yes || echo no
wmic product where caption="Yava Auto Updater" get name /value 2>nul |find "=" >nul && echo yes || echo no
```